# General partial fraction decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I was wondering what was the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{(X - a_1)(X - a_2) \cdots (X - a_{n - 1})}{(X + b_1) \cdots (X + b_n)}$ with $a_n$ and $b_n$ real positive numbers. In fact we have  $\frac{c_1}{X + b_1} + \cdots + \frac{c_n}{X + b_n}$. Where $c_n$ :
$$c_n=\frac{(b_n + a_1)(b_n + a_2)\cdots(b_n + a_{n-1})}{(b_n - b_1) \cdots (b_n - b_{n-1})}.$$

But how to prove it ?
My main idea is to use the Laurent series but I don't know how...Or an other way will be to calculate a Vandermonde's Determinant with two differents ways to get the desired result ,after that I have no more ideas .

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you have to assume the $b_k$ are all distinct.  Write your equation
as 
$$ \frac{(X-a_1)(X-a_2)\ldots(X-a_{n-1})}{(X+b_1)\ldots(X+b_{n-1})} = 
\frac{c_1 (X+b_n)}{X-b_1} + \ldots + \frac{c_{n-1}(X+b_n)}{X+b_{n-1}} + c_n $$
and substitute $X = -b_n$.  Note that all terms on the right except $c_n$ are $0$.